# При клике на пункт должно появляться выпадающее меню

Tags: javascript, css3, меню, dropdown

Можно ли сделать выпадающее меню с CSS
https://codepen.io/pen/gymgBj

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Law firm</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="logo.jpg" class="logo">

    <div class="navbar"><ul>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <ul>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
      <a href="#">Link 5</a></ul>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#news">Blog</a></ul>

</div>
    </header>
     <script>

  </script>
</body>
</html> 

        .dropdown-content{
    display: none;
    border:none;
    position: absolute;
    }
    .dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1em;
}
    .dropdown .dropbtn{
        font-size: 1.8em;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    .navbar > ul {
    display: block;
    max-width: 400px;
    }
    .navbar a{
        font-size: 1.8em;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Клик в css можно отслеживать с помощью, например, checkbox. Создаёте соответствующий input type="checkbox", скрываете его, а вместо button используете label, который можете стилизовать как захотите:

```css
.dropdown-content{
    display: none;
    border:none;
    position: absolute;
    }
    .dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1em;
}
[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
    .dropdown .dropbtn{
        font-size: 1.8em;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 2px solid maroon;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        margin: 5px 0;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
    #dropbtn:checked ~ .dropdown-content {
       display: block;
     }
    .navbar > ul {
    display: block;
    max-width: 400px;
    }
    .navbar a{
        font-size: 1.8em;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<header>
        <img src="logo.jpg" class="logo">

    <div class="navbar"><ul>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
  <input type="checkbox" id="dropbtn" />
    <label for="dropbtn" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
    </label>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
      <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></ul>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#news">Blog</a></ul>

</div>
    </header>
```

Но вообще можно сделать выпадение по наведению - тогда не нужны никакие инпуты и лейблы, всё остаётся как есть, добавляется только соответствующий ховер:

```css
.dropdown-content{
    display: none;
    border:none;
    position: absolute;
    }
    .dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1em;
}
    .dropdown .dropbtn{
        font-size: 1.8em;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
     .dropdown .dropbtn:hover ~ .dropdown-content,
     .dropdown-content:hover {
       display: block;
     }
    .navbar > ul {
    display: block;
    max-width: 400px;
    }
    .navbar a{
        font-size: 1.8em;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<header>
        <img src="logo.jpg" class="logo">

    <div class="navbar"><ul>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
      <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></ul>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#news">Blog</a></ul>

</div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Именно, что у меня есть выпадающее меню в полноэкранном режиме, сейчас для удобства -для мобильных версий лучше - при клике

Comment: @adelya, ну, тогда переделайте на вариант с инпутом

Comment: хорошо,попробую, спасибо